# Как принудительно прервать выполнение предыдущих запросов AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Имеем небольшую форму, где есть поле ввода логина, отправляется ajax запрос после каждого введённого символа, если ник есть, ставится картинка галочки, если нет - крестик. Проблема в том что если быстро напечатать ник то эти картинки высветят результат на каждый символ. Выходит что я быстро пишу свой ник и потом жду пару секунд пока все галочки и крестики аккуратно появятся и уберутся, в итоге через пару секунд миганий появляется нужная мне картинка.

Необходимо, видимо, прерывать принудительно предыдущие запросы AJAX вопрос только как?

```js
$(".nick-pay-donate").on('input',function () {

    var checkNick = $(".nick-pay-donate").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../handlers/checkNick.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: ({nick: checkNick}),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == '1') {
                $(".nick-icon").fadeOut( 300 ).attr({'src':'/assets/icons/tick.svg','title':'Ник действительно существует в нашей системе'}).fadeIn( 300 );
            } else {
                $(".nick-icon").fadeOut( 300 ).attr({'src':'/assets/icons/close.svg','title':'Данный ник не зарегистрирован в нашей системе'}).fadeIn( 300 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: банально можно считать запросы. отправляем новый запрос - увеличиваем счетчик. Пришел запрос, если у него номер (замыкание) меньше чем уже число отправленных, то игнорируем его обработку. Вообще нет особого смысла слать запрос на каждое нажатие клавиши. Пусть в среднем пользователь печатает 300символов в минуту, получается между нажатиями например по 12мс. Возьмите к этому небольшой лаг времени (якобы пользователь закончил писать), например, +10мс, и отправляйте запрос не каждое нажатие, а только если с момента последнего нажатия прошли эти 22мс.

Comment: @teran вы очень хорошего мнения о скорости пользовательского ввода. По моему опыту я всегда ставлю debounce на 500мс. Ну уж никак не 22мс :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko потому что натупил и не 60сек на 300симвлов разделил, а 3600 :) 0.2секунды между нажатиями, в целом да, двойной интервал и будет 0.4с, и больше при уменьшении скорости печати, так что 500мс хорошее значение.

Comment: я вообще что-то затрудняюсь сказать что я на что делил, что получилось 12мс :D

Comment: @teran интересно, какое время суток было, когда вы оставляли комментарий :))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko обеденное :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких вещей обычно используют `debounce`.

```js
// создаем debounce функцию, которая будет вызываться через 500 мс после последнего вызова
var debounceOnInput = debounce(onInput, 500);

function onInput() {
  var checkNickOld = $(".nick-pay-donate").val();
  console.log('request', checkNickOld);
  // Эмулируем AJAX запрос
  setTimeout(function() {
    var checkNick = $(".nick-pay-donate").val();
    if (checkNickOld === checkNick) {
      console.log('response', checkNick);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
// при изменении значения в инпуте, вызываем debounce функцию
$(".nick-pay-donate").on('input', debounceOnInput);

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nick-pay-donate">
```

Comment: Где тут я должен вставить запрос на получения ника (скрипт php возвращает 1 или 0)

Comment: @DmitryDevelop а вы немного подумайте, посмотрите код, почитайте комментарии в коде. *// Эмулируем AJAX запрос* видите вот это? Что же это может означать....